# How to add nodes to a dijit tree on the fly

Tags: tree, dojo, addition, nodes

Basically what I have is a tree with 3 nodes, created like so:

```
        for (var i=0; i<response.length; i++) {
            response[i]["type"] = "project";
        }

        var data = {
            "identifier": "name",
            "label": "name",
            "items": response
        };

        var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data: data});
        console.log(store);

        var treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
            store: store,
            query: {
                "type": "project"
            },
            rootId: "root",
            rootLabel: "Projects",
            childrenAttrs: ["project"]
        });

        return new dijit.Tree({
            model: treeModel
        },
        "filetree");
```

Now what I need to do is, when a user clicks on a node, I will make a call to the server to get some more data, and then add some children to said node. From what I have read, I have to update my data store to update the tree ... but I can't figure this out. Some help is appreciated.